# How to recursively get dependent resources of Kubernetes owner resource

Tags: kubernetes, garbage-collection, kubectl

With Kubernetes you can use the [Garbage Collector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/garbage-collection/) to automate the deletion of dependent resources when owning resources are removed. I'm wondering the easiest method to print out the dependency tree of an owning resource, potentially limiting to a tree depth if needs be.

I understand the potential for crashing the API service given the ability to fan out to all resources in a cluster and likely why this isn't an easy feat to achieve but I've been struggling to even find usable, community supported workarounds or even discussions/issues relating to this topic (likely my poor searching skills) so any help in achieving this would be great!

---

To make things more concrete a specific example of an abstract `kubectl get` query I'd like to achieve would be something like `kubectl get scheduledworkflow <workflow name> --dependents`:

- This would find the Kubeflow Pipelines `ScheduledWorkflow` resource then recurse,
- That would find all Argo `Workflow` resources,
- Then for each `Workflow` resource many `Pod` and `Volume` resources (there are a few other types but wanted to paint the picture of these being disparate resource types).

We typically only keep a small number of Argo `Workflow` resources in the cluster at anyone one time as the majority of our `Workflow`'s spawn 1k+ `Pod` so we have pretty aggressive GC policies in place. Even so listing these is just painful at the moment and need to use a custom script to do it but wondering if there was a higher level CLI, SDK or API available (or any group working on this issue in the community!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no ready solutions for this.

I see two options how this can be proceeded:

---

**1 -** probably this is what you already mentioned: "need to use a custom script to do it".

Idea is to get `json`s of required resource groups and then process it by any available/known language like bash/python/java/etc and/or using `jq`. All dependent objects have `ownerReference` field which allows to match resources.

[More information about owners and dependents](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/owners-dependents/)

[jq tool and examples](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2018/06/28/more-handy-cli-tools-json/)

---

**2 -** Write your own tool based on kubernetes garbage collector

Kubernetes garbage collector works based on `graph` built by `GraphBuilder`:

[garbage collector source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/garbagecollector/garbagecollector.go#L56-L79)

Graph is always up to date by using `reflectors:

> GarbageCollector runs reflectors to watch for changes of managed API
> objects, funnels the results to a single-threaded
> dependencyGraphBuilder, which builds a graph caching the dependencies
> among objects

[graph_builder source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/garbagecollector/graph_builder.go) to get whole logic of it.

Built `graph` has `node` type:

[graph data structure](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/controller/garbagecollector/graph.go#L42-L62)

Also it's worth to mention that working with `api server` is more convenient using [kubernetes clients libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) which are available for different languages.

Comment: Sure did, thanks for the detailed run down!